# Assign a string field of a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, c-strings

I try to write a program using this structure containing strings :

```
typedef struct s_conf
{
    char *shell1;
    char *shell2;
    char *shell3;
    char *shell4;
    char *server_ip;    
} t_conf;
```

Parsing a config text file line per line, I get this information and I store it into variables such as line1 and line4. Now I want to assign my struct fields the values of the variables line1 and line4:

```
char *line1 = "/var/www/host/current/app/console robot:file";
char *line4 = "192.168.00.00";

t_conf *conf;
if ((conf = malloc(sizeof(t_conf))) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Malloc error\n");
            return (-1);
        }

strcpy(conf->shell1, line1);
strcpy(conf->server_ip, line4);

printf("line1 : '%s'\n"; line1);
printf("line4 : '%s'\n"; line4);

printf("t_conf->shell1 : '%s'\n", conf->shell1);
printf("t_conf->server_ip : '%s'\n", conf->server_ip);
```

The output :

```
line1 : '/var/www/host/current/app/console robot:file'
line4 : '192.168.00.00'
t_conf->shell1 : '/var/www/host/current/app'
t_conf->server_ip : '192.168.00.00'
```

How to correctly assign the c string t_conf->shell1 ? 
I try other functions like memcpy(), strdup() and allocate the variable with malloc : `t_conf->shell1 = malloc(strlen(line1) + 1)` but it gives me the same result, I lose a portion of line1 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
strcpy(conf->shell1, line1);
```

You need space to store `line1`

Furthermore (as pointed out by @cat in comments) `strcpy` is dangerous and must be avoided in production code, an alternative is `strdup` (non standard), or `snprintf`:

```
size_t size = strlen(line1) + 1;
conf->shell1 = malloc(size);
snprintf(conf->shell1, size, "%s", line1);
```

The space should be returned with `free(conf->shell1);` when it is no longer needed.

Same for `conf->server_ip`

Note that if you don't need to modify those strings, you don't need to copy, just assign:

```
conf->shell1 = line1;
```

Comment: Don't recommend the use of `strcpy` and `strndup`, please. Instead, `strndup` and `strnlen` are POSIX.1-2008.

Comment: @cat: you probably mean strdup (on the left side). Also, `strlcpy` can be a good choice.

Comment: @cat right you are, edited, IMO a better choice is `snprintf` since its standard

Comment: @Aif Yeah, I mistyped it. `strlcpy` seems to be BSD, which means I can get it on a GNU/Linux machine with `-lbsd`, or by default on BSD but not anything else.

Comment: Suggesting `snprintf()` with out showing how to handle the problems it causes simply trades one problem of buffer overflow (using `sprintf()`) with incomplete "printing" - which this code certainly does.

Comment: With `conf->shell1 = malloc(sizeof(line1));`, why allocate using the size of a pointer?

Comment: @chux The obviously detectable problems introduced by snprintf (i.e, not enough data being formatted) are far easier to solve than hidden buffer overflows possible through strcpy, sprintf and strdup

Comment: @cat Yes detectable problems are easier to solve than hidden ones.  A good answer would show that easy solution.  Unclear on your concern about buffer overflows  through `strdup()`.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to write a program using this structure containing strings :

`struct s_conf` below contains 5 *pointers*.  It does not contains any *strings*.  With the C standard library, a *string* is an *array* of characters up to and including a final null character (`'\0'`).  For your code to work, memory for these arrays are needed - someplace.

```
typedef struct s_conf {
    char *shell1;
    char *shell2;
    char *shell3;
    char *shell4;
    char *server_ip;    
} t_conf;
```

`strcpy(conf->shell1, line1);` fails because `conf->shell1` does not yet have a value pointing to available memory for the copy.

---

Populate these 5 pointers with values pointing to memory containing the needed data.

```
// allocate memory for the structure
conf = malloc(sizeof *conf);
assert(conf);

// Simply copy the pointer if `line1` will exist for as long as `conf`.
conf->shell1 = line1;

// or
// Create an allocated copy.
conf->shell1 = strdup(line1);
// With this method, be sure to free the memory before freeing conf
...
free(conf->shell1);
free(conf);
```

---

`strdup()` is not a standard library function, yet very common.  Make an equivalent if needed.  Example: (tailor to your needs)

```
char *my_strdup(const char *s) {
  if (s) {
    size_t sz = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *dest = malloc(sz);
    if (dest) {
      return memcpy(dest, src, sz);
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```